Nginx sub_filter doesn't work
Nginx sub_filter doesn't replace string.
nginx conf:
location / {
    proxy_pass https://internal.domain.tld:8081/phpmyadmin/;
    rewrite ^/phpmyadmin/(.*) /$1;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path '/';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Rewrite internal redirects
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter '/phpmyadmin/' '/';

    proxy_redirect /phpmyadmin/ /;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
}

html in which it should be replaced:
<head>
...
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
CommonParams.setAll({common_query:"lang=en",...is_https:true,rootPath:"/phpmyadmin/",...user:"root"});
var firstDayOfCalendar = '0';
...


One possible cause of this issue is that compression is enabled on your internal.domain.tld:8081 host. To address this, you can try preventing the Accept-Encoding HTTP header from being passed along with the client request by using the proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; directive.

If your only goal is to properly set PHPMyAdmin root URL, you should just set $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] configuration value to https://example.com/phpmyadmin.
That will tell PHPMyAdmin what base URL to use for generating all URLs.
Then you can remove all sub_filter, proxy_redirect and proxy_cookie_path directives.

No, my goal is to do this with sub_filter, without touching phpmyadmin configuration at all.

Using sub_filter is not the proper solution here. The issue is that you cannot easily tell it to change only the instances that are needed. For example, if the page visible content should have /phpmyadmin/ in it, that is impossible with sub_filter.

I'm not asking for the proper solution, I'm asking why it doesn't work.

Have you tried sub_filter /phpmyadmin/ /, that is, without quotes?
